# What should I prove to show the states lie within a compact set?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions

I'm trying to prove the local stability of a nonlinear system and got the following inequality.
$
\|x(t)\|\leq c_1\|x(t_0)\|\exp(-c_2(t-t_0))+c_3\epsilon_m\cdots
$(i)

where $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are positive constants.

Now, since the approximation error has upper bound $\epsilon_m=\sup_{x \in \mathcal{X}}\| \epsilon(x)\|$ only within a compact set $\mathcal{X}$ of feasible system states, to complete the proof, I have to prove that $x$ always lies in $\mathcal{X}$.

But I have no idea where to start or what assumption is needed to justify the stability.

Off the top of my head, the assumption $x_0 \in \mathcal{X}, c_3<1$ seems to work cuz with this assumption, $x$ starts inside the set and exponentially converges to a smaller ball than $\epsilon_m$.

Please let me know your thought

---

Here's the background for your information.

1. The system is $\dot{x}=Ax+B(u+f_u(x))$ where $f_u$ is an unknown disturbance. By the control input $u=-\hat{f}_u(x)$, the closed-loop dynamics becomes $\dot{x}=Ax+B(u+\epsilon)$ with the estimation error $\epsilon=f_u(x)-\hat{f}_u(x)$. (I've got (i) by applying the Comparison lemma to this system.)
2. $f_u(x), \hat{f}_u(x)$ has the same Lipschitz constant, so does $\epsilon$
3. $\mathcal{X}$ is where $\epsilon$ is bounded, which means $\|f_u(x^\prime)-\hat{f}_u(x) \|< L_u \|x^\prime - x\|$ with $L_u$ being the Lipshitz constant of $f_u$

Comment: Did you get this result with a Lyapunov function? Can you show it?

Comment: @Arastas Yes, the Lyapunov is $x^\top P x$ with $P$ being positive semi definite, and applied the Comparison lemma to it. (it's kinda complicated so I omitted that part. Should I show the whole process?)

Comment: @Arastas It is also noted that this system is almost linear like this $\dot{x}=Ax+B(u+\epsilon)$ and P is the one satisfying the Algebraic Riccati Equation (ARE).

Comment: It is sometimes simpler to study invariant sets by Lypunov function.

Comment: I dont think your argument works, even if you assume that $x_0\in\mathcal{X}$: First of all, $x$ might not directly converge to a smaller ball, because $\epsilon_m$ leaves room above the upper bound for $\Vert x(t) \Vert$ such that $\Vert x(t) \Vert$ might grow locally. And second, $\Vert x(t) \Vert$ might satisfy the inequality even in some subset of the state space that is not part of $\mathcal{X}$. So even if you start in $\mathcal{X}$, I think there is no guarantee  that you stay in $\mathcal{X}$, and outside of $\mathcal{X}$, anything might happen, including instability.

Comment: @Arastas In this time, $\epsilon$ is the tricky one so I think applying comparison lemma seems to work simpler

Comment: @SampleTime Thank you for the insight. How about another condition $c_3<1$? It seems to leave no space for $\|x\|$ to grow locally. And if this doesn't work too, what do you think necessary assumption is?

Comment: @SpaceTAKA I don't see how that additional condition would change anything. I still leaves space for $\Vert x \Vert$ to grow locally, namely precisely the offset $c_3 \epsilon_m$. Even if $c_3<1$, still $\epsilon_m$ could itself be large, so the offset could be large. And even if there were no room for local growth, the argument still couldn't work because $\Vert x\Vert$ could satisfy the exponential inequality while leaving $\mathcal{X}$ and even outside of $\mathcal{X}$. But outside of $\mathcal{X}$, $\epsilon(x)$ might blow up to infinity, so $\epsilon_m$ might not even exist anymore.

Comment: @SampleTime Thank you, and, yes exactly. So I got to show $x$ stays inside $\mathcal{X}$, do you have any idea to show it?

Comment: @SpaceTAKA I don't think it is possible to answer this question without more details about $\epsilon(x)$ and $\mathcal{X}$ and your system. This is simply because there will be combinations of systems and compact sets of feasible states that satisfy all your conditions but admit instability nevertheless. And there will be stable combinations. So the answer depends on the missing details.

Comment: @SampleTime Thank you. Here is the detail: The system is $\dot{x}=Ax +B(u+f_u)$ where $f_u$ is unknown disturbance. By the control input $u=-\hat{f}_u$, the closed-loop dynamics becomes $\dot{x}=Ax +B(u+\epsilon)$ with the estimation error $\epsilon=f_u-\hat{f}_u$. Note that $f_u, \hat{f}_u $has the same Lipschitz constant, so does $\epsilon$.

Comment: @SampleTime $\mathcal{X}$ is where $\epsilon$ is bounded, which means $\|f_u(x^\prime)-\hat{f}_u(x) \|< L_u \|x^\prime - x\|$ with $L_u$ being the Lipshitz constant of $f_u$

Comment: @SampleTime I added the aforementioned info to this post. Should I post another question for this?